# Rotate rectangular element 90 degrees on a grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

I'm making a webapp where you can place elements on a grid, move them around and rotate them.

I've run into a problem regarding the rotation of the elements, if the width is an odd number and the height is even and vice versa.

When rotating around the centre of the element, the new coordinates for the element will end off being in halves.

[image]   [image]

The rotation happens when im adding a class to the element using jQuery, and the actual rotation is made by CSS.

I need to get the element to line up with the grid after a "faulty" rotation. How can i achieve this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is the sub-pixel position causing an actual problem, or does it just seem as though it must be wrong?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Sorry, Im new to StackOverflow. I just added the question.

Comment: @izb The sub cell positioning is a problem since all of the elements on the grid has to line up perfectly.

Comment: Oh, so the grid is not the pixel grid?

Comment: @izb The grid is just a background image repeating in a div; Thats why it is possible to place elements at eg. 12.5 , 23.5.

Comment: If it's just the rectangle to rotate, you could also switch height and width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using CSS to rotate your element, you could also use the tranform origin property to make the rectangle rotate around one of the grid nodes and stay aligned. For your example with a 5*2 rectangle the transform origin should be :

```
transform-origin: 40% 50%;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2xdr4b8a/)** ***(Hover the rectangle to rotate it)***

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
.b{
    float:left;
    width:9.5vw;
    height:9.5vw;
    background:#262C33;
    border:1px solid grey;
}

.r{
    position:absolute;
    left:19vw; top: 28.5vw;
    width:47.5vw; height:19vw;
    border:2px solid #fff;
}
.r:hover{
    transform-origin: 40% 50%;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>

<div class="r"></div>
```